# HTTP POST request - sending username and password to the server

Tags: iphone

I'm a newcomer to the iPhone world. I'm working on an application having a login page. I have to send `UIText` value of username and password to the server. Code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the user_ name and password from  the severer ASIHTTPRequest framework 
it's the ex. of code  which from the twitter request.m file

```
if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
    NSURLCredential *newCredential;
    newCredential=[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:[self username]
                                             password:[self password]
                                          persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential
           forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    [newCredential release];
} else {
    [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    // inform the user that the user name and password
    // in the preferences are incorrect
    NSLog(@"Invalid Username or Password");
}
```

Comment: 0  down vote  favorite
1
 

I m a new comer to the iPhone world,m working on an application having login page,i have to send UIText value of username and Passworld value to the server with the help of SOAP(MUST),I am having no idea regarding the same...plz help me out,code would b appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Look into using the [ASIHTTPRequest framework](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to make POST requests.